# How to do Collection Field Unique in Meteor JS?

Tags: meteor

I need to know about collection field unique in meteor js. I have created one collection as shown below:

```
  List= new Meteor.Collection("list");
```

The above collection contains 5 fields they are listed below :

```
 1. User Name

 2. Email

 3. Name

 4. Qualification

 5. Status
```

In the above fields i need to do unique are User name & Email.So is there any procedure for unique fields in a collection or do manually checking when ever inserts data to a collection each & every time.Please suggest me what to do for this above problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create unique indices on the server. This way, Mongo checks it for you:

```
List._ensureIndex({username: 1}, {unique: 1});
List._ensureIndex({email: 1}, {unique: 1});
```

See how Meteor does it for `Meteor.users`: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L1136

Comment: What is sparse in user collection.Can you please explain the use of sparse in user collection?.@Andrew Mao.

Comment: [Mongo spark indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/) mean that the document will not be indexed if the index field is not present. Please read [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/) for full implementation details and implications.

Comment: The above one is working fine but how to known this is username already exist error or may be some thing like error using above procedure while inserts fields to collection.@Andrew Mao

Comment: @Venkat. If you try to insert into the collection a document where the username already exists, you will get an error. So just `try`/`catch`.

Comment: Isn't ensureIndex deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Collection2 with SimpleSchema:

!: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2

2: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema